# How to re-use configuration/includes from another layer?

Tags: yocto, yocto-layer, yocto-kirkstone

Suppose I am using a third-party Yocto layer, and I have also created my own layer.

The third party layer has lots of config files (for instance, machine configurations) which all `include` one common file.

In my own layer, I'd like to create my own configuration, which will be much like the third-party ones. Can I `include` that common file, without hard-coding the other layer's path?

For a real-world example, see the `meta-intel-fpga` layer:

https://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-intel-fpga/tree/recipes-kernel/linux?h=kirkstone

If I created a new layer (which depends on meta-intel-fpga) I would expect to be able to create a new recipe for a new kernel version (one not already supported by meta-intel-fpga), and ideally avoid duplicating the `.inc` file.

Comment: What is your goal exactly? Do you like to use linux-socfpga.inc in your custom recipe?
https://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-intel-fpga/tree/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-socfpga.inc?h=kirkstone

Comment: @Livius yes, suppose that i wanted to write a recipe `linux-socfpga_6.0.bb`. 6.0 is not currently offered in meta-intel-fpga, i'd be adding support for that in my custom layer. my recipe would want to include the `linux-socfpga.inc` file.

Comment: another example would be: suppose a third-party BSP layer has machine `.conf` files, and my layer has defined a new, derivative machine with its own `.conf` file. the third-party machines all include one common file (with qemu settings, for instance) and it would be nice for my custom `.conf` to include that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Usually we create [bbappend](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/1.6/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#using-bbappend-files) files to modify existing recipes (e.g. if you only want to change a few things in that recipe). This is the preferred method as it avoids duplicating recipes, and you will get the updates coming from that layer.

If you want to create your own recipe using the `.inc` files provided by the third-party layer (e.g. to use a version that is not provided by the third-party layer), you'll need to include it and specify the path using something like `require recipes-kernel/linux/linux-socfpga.inc` in your new recipe.

Note that if you do this you may need to set a [PREFERRED_VERSION](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/1.6/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#var-PREFERRED_VERSION) or give your layer a [higher priority](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev/dev-manual/layers.html#prioritizing-your-layer) to ensure your recipe is used instead of the ones provided in the third-party layer.

Comment: the meta-intel-fpga example shows recipes for several 5.x versions of the kernel. all of the recipes use the same `.inc` file. i have a layer that depends on meta-intel-fpga, and in my layer i want to create a new recipe for the 6.0 kernel. in this case, i cannot use a `.bbappend` file, it must be a new `.bb` file, and i cannot include/require the original `.inc` file.

Answer (score 1):

For including you should use `include recipes-kernel/linux/linux-socfpga.inc` in your bbappend.

Comment: You don't need to include anything in the `bbappend`, it's already done in the recipe (`.bb`). And if he creates his own recipe a `require` would be better than an `include` as it will fail if the `.inc` is not found (as it should).